# Setter error with Laravel 4.2, HHVM, and Carbon

Tags: php, laravel-4, hhvm

I'm trying to run an application on an HHVM 3.2 server and I'm getting a 'InvalidArgumentException Unknown setter '_date_time' error. It seems to have something to do with the magic functions. It also looks like it's coming from Carbon and due to the sessions being created.

I'm using Redis database for session management since I'm using HAPROXY for load balancing. Anyone else come across this issue and is there a fix?

Oddly I have another Laravel 4.2 (earlier version) application running on the same setup and it runs fine.

Here is the stack error:

```
InvalidArgumentException …/­vendor/­nesbot/­carbon/­src/­Carbon/­Carbon.php542
Carbon\Carbon __set <#unknown>0
DateTime __sleep <#unknown>0
serialize …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Session/­Store.php222
Illuminate\Session\Store save …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Session/­Middleware.php126
Illuminate\Session\Middleware closeSession …/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Session/­Middleware.php79
```

Comment: having a similar issue. It's a problem on HHVM's end and they still haven't fixed it.